# Get apachesolr module to work with solr 5.5 without reindexing

Tags: 7, search

I upgraded my drupal apachesolr search module from 1.8 to 1.11 and I also upgrade the apachesolr version from version 4.10 to 5.5, and managed to upgrade the index folder so that it can be used for 5.5 solr search. But once I change the drupal apache solr URL to connect to the new 5.5 solr search, it ask me to reindex everything again. Is there a way to avoid this step?

Comment: No, you updated a major version of solr. I'd expect a good deal of change in the conf files and especially if you had to make a new core - you will need to reindex.

Comment: no not new core. it is using existing core with upgraded index. It works on the solr web admin but not on drupal